# How can I implement login and membership in asp.net core with Cassandra database

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cassandra, identity, membership

I want to use asp.net core identity in my project for membership, login, etc. and I want to use cassandra database instead of sql server

Answer (score 0):

There is a cassandra c# driver. Here is a tutorial. A quick google search yield this.
https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/cassandra/using-cassandra/connect-to-cassandra-with-c-sharp/

Comment: thanks. but this link only shows using cassandra in asp.net core and not showing using identity with casandra

Comment: You seed the identity data as you would normally. You can google .net core identity. Once you have the db you can use EF or other methods to seed the identity schema over.